# Using ng-options for select when using as notation for controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-controlleras

I have a select using ng-options to define the options which works fine when I use just the controller name within the ng-controller directive. The problem is that when I add "as options" to the ng-controller it no longer works (no options).

Doesn't work:

```
<div ng-controller="optionsCtrl as options">
    <select ng-model="options.oxygenSource" ng-options="item.name for item in options.oxygenSources"></select><br />
</div>
```

Works:

```
<div ng-controller="optionsCtrl">
    <select ng-model="oxygenSource" ng-options="item.name for item in oxygenSources"></select>
</div>
```

Here's my controller if it helps:

```
.controller('optionsCtrl', ['$scope', 'adminServ', function ($scope, adminServ) {
    // User selections
    $scope.oxygenSource = null;

    $scope.oxygenSources = adminServ.getOxygenSources();
}])
```

Any thoughts? Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the `controller` when you are using `controllerAs` syntax. Controller should use `this` keyword instead of `$scope`.

**Controller**

```
.controller('optionsCtrl', ['$scope', 'adminServ', function ($scope, adminServ) {
    var options = this;
    options.oxygenSource = null;
    options.oxygenSources = adminServ.getOxygenSources();
}])
```

[**ControllerAs article**](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) for info by Todd motto

Comment: Yep, that was exactly the problem! I'll accept it in 5 minutes when it lets me.  And extra thanks for that article, it looks helpful.